# Upload Multiple file drag drop codeigniter with multiple category

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using codeigniter.Now I want to upload multiple file with multiple category using dropzone-js.

my data base tables are

table category

```
id   title

1   test
2   test 2
3   test 2
```

Table Image

```
id  image

1   s.jpg
```

table image _category

```
id image_id  category _id

1     1         1    
2     1         3
```

Now describe my form

my from

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('/image/upload'); ?>" class="dropzone dz-clickable">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="checkboxes">Inline Checkboxes</label>
    <div class="controls">
     <label class="checkbox inline" for="checkboxes-0">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-0" value="1">
              test
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox inline" for="checkboxes-1">
         <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-1" value="2">test 2
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox inline" for="checkboxes-2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-2" value="3">test 3</label>   
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="control-group">

      <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>

     </div>  
    </form>
```

now when user upload image more then one or only on then user can select one or two or all category.

when user drop image in dropzone area then it will be upload in server and information goes to db.

in my given table structure there one image uploaded under two category.
It may can be multiple image.

i am writing this code in controller

```
class Image extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->helper(array('url','html','form'));
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('dropzone_view');
    }

    public function upload() {
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $targetPath = getcwd() . '/uploads/';
        $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);


        }
    }
}
```

But I cant understand how to upload file in db with category

Answer (score 0):

dropzone uploads files 1 in each ajax post request, you need to create controller which will receive these files and will upload each image one by 1 as you would upload 1 image at a time. (i'm using Verot upload library for image processing at example)

controller:

```
/**
 * Method for drop down upload form server side upload handling
 */
public function upload()
{
    $this->load->model('image_upload_model');
        if (!empty($_FILES))
        {
            $this->image_upload_model->upload_image('1024', './media/wysiwyg/', $_FILES['file']);
        }
}
```

model for upload:

```
/**
 * Method for uploading Images from dropdown form.
 *
 * @param $size
 * @param $path
 * @param $file
 */
public function upload_image($size = '', $path = '', $file= '')
{
    $this->load->library('verot_upload');
    $foo = new Verot_upload();
    $new_path_large = '';

    // Upload large image and set $new_path_large
    // as large image location on web folder
    $foo->upload($file);
    if ($foo->uploaded)
    {
        $foo->image_resize = true;
        $foo->image_x = $size;
        $foo->image_ratio_y = true;
        $foo->Process($path);
        if ($foo->processed)
        {
            $new_path_large = substr($foo->file_dst_pathname,1);
        }
    }

    // Create thumbnail from original image and
    // set $new_pat_thumb as thumbnail file location on web folder
    $foo->upload($file);
    if ($foo->uploaded)
    {
        $foo->image_resize = true;
        $foo->image_x = 233;
        $foo->image_ratio_y = true;
        $foo->Process($path.'thumb/');
        if ($foo->processed)
        {
            $new_path_thumb = substr($foo->file_dst_pathname,1);

            // Save data in database
            $this
                ->db
                ->set('date_created', 'NOW()', false)
                ->set('path', $new_path_large, true)
                ->set('thumbnail', $new_path_thumb, true)
                ->insert('wysiwyg_img_uploads');
        }
    }

}
```

and form:

```
<div class="columns large-19 medium-9 small-12">
    <form action="/admin/images/upload"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="post"
          class="dropzone"
          id="my-awesome-dropzone">
          </form>
</div>
<script src="/skin/js/dropzone.js"></script>
```